# How do I send a JavaScript variable into a PHP file via $.ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How do I send the JavaScript variable exampleId into the https://example.com/widget/widget-updater.php php file from within the $.ajax() function below?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {   

var element = document.getElementById('widget');
var exampleId = element.getAttribute('attributeExample');

alert(exampleId); /* This prints out correctly into a pop up box */



$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "https://example.com/widget/widget-updater.php"
});        

})();
```

I know how to get the variable once its in PHP with $_GET['exampleId'], but I don't know how to send it to the PHP file via the $.ajax() function above. Thanks.

**Here is the HTML Code:**

```
<script 
src="https://example.com/widget/externalJSfileContainingTheCodeBelow.js" 
async></script><div id="widget" dataVar="1"></div>
```

**Here is the Javascript / jQuery Code**

```
(function () {
var jQuery;
if (window.jQuery === undefined) {
var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
script_tag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
script_tag.setAttribute("src",
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js");
if (script_tag.readyState) {
script_tag.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
scriptLoadHandler();
}
};
} else {
  script_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
}
(document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] ||
  document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
} else {
jQuery = window.jQuery;
main();
}

function scriptLoadHandler() {
jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
main();
}

function main() {
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

var element = document.getElementById('widget');
var numberVariable = element.getAttribute('dataVar');
alert(numberVariable);

$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "https://example.com/widget/widget-updater.php",
data: { id: numberVariable }
});
var css_link = $("<link>", {
rel: "stylesheet",
type: "text/css",
href: "https://example.com/widget/widget.css"
});
css_link.appendTo('head');
var jsonp_url = "https://example.com/cgi-bin/data.py?callback=?";
$.getJSON(jsonp_url, function (data) {
$('#widget').html(data.html);
});
});
}
})();
```

Comment: `url: "https://example.com/widget/widget-updater.php?exampleId=" + exampleId`

Comment: Issue with this is that exampleId won't display its value, it's like its out of scope.

Comment: Shouldn't be out of scope. Show  us your relevant html also as in [mcve]

Comment: See above, this is a tricky problem.

Comment: data: { id: numberVariable } just prints as data: { id: numberVariable } when run in javascript. It literally prints the word numberVariable and not the value of the variable.

Comment: One problem I can see is that `$.ajax` runs asynchronously, so you'll probably want to move the code below inside the ajax call's `success` function (which doesn't exist yet)

Comment: That's a good idea. So I should create a success function?

Comment: How would I write the code for that in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `data` object in the ajax config.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   data:{'exampleId' : exampleId},
   url: "https://example.com/widget/widget-updater.php"
});
```

Internally jQuery will create the query string in url from that when it is a GET and will become

```
"https://example.com/widget/widget-updater.php?exampleId=12345"
```

You can manually create the query string instead  but using an object is cleaner and less work and less error prone

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a GET response you can pass data in a query parameter.

Your ajax URL is going to look like this: https://example.com/widget/widget-updater.php?exampleId=YOURDATA

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "https://example.com/widget/widget-updater.php?exampleId=data"
});
```

From PHP you can use `$_GET['exampleId']` and is going to give you `data`

Comment: Issue with this is that exampleId won't display its value, it's like its out of scope.

Comment: Right...have to concatenate the variable in or in modern browsers use template literal

Comment: this is what it prints in javascript when run in the browser ---- 
   url: "https://example.com/widget/widget-updater.php? 
   exampleId="+data --- it doesn't actually print the value of the javascript variable.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the `method` of `GET` you can simply apend your `URL` IE:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "https://example.com/widget/widget-updater.php?id=12345&foo=bar"
});
```

ALTERNATIVELY you can use the `data` attribute in `.ajax()` IE

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
data:{id : '123456', foo: 'bar'},
url: "https://example.com/widget/widget-updater.php"
});
```

Comment: Issue with this is that exampleId won't display its value, it's like its out of scope.

Comment: I have and it doesn't print the value of exampleId when run in javascript. It prints the actual word "exampleId"